# Are the CRM 2011 early bound APIs safe to use with the Task Parallel Library?

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, task-parallel-library

I am experiencing intermittent SaveChangesException when creating CRM entities using the early binding APIs (generated context) via a Threading.Task.

Using the code below I am able to recreate the exception - note that it is intermittent and I can have several runs without experiencing it.

As you can see there is no shared state in my code, I am creating the CRM Connection, service and context per operation.

The exception thrown is:

> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException: An error occured while processing this request. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Am I missing something here or are the early bound SDK classes unsafe to use in a multi-threaded environment?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(1, 400))
            {
                var capturedIndex = index;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CreateContact(capturedIndex));
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void CreateContact(int i)
        {
            var contact = new Contact {FirstName = "Test", LastName = string.Concat("Contact_", i)};
            var context = new XrmServiceContext(new OrganizationService(new CrmConnection("Crm")));  // The generated context is taken from the SDK samples
            context.AddObject(contact);

            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Contact created - ", i));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);            
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I happened to notice similar strangeness when using Parallel.For in a console app, but I was just using the late-bound Entity object.  My code looked very similar but uses the OrganizationService.Create method.  Very strange!

Comment: As far as the contexts are concerned, you should have one per task/thread. I don't have an answer, but could this be a limitation of the Organization web service (like wcf's maxconcurrentcalls?)

Comment: Is there anything more to the stack trace in the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurs at a lower level within the WCF configuration. For those using late-bound entities, a workaround is to disable the ProxyTypesEnabled property on the CrmConnection. Another workaround is to set the ServiceConfigurationMode to PerInstance but unfortunately, this comes with a performance hit. Note: both of these can be set through the connection string as well.

```
var connection1 = new CrmConnection("Crm")
{
    ProxyTypesEnabled = false
}; // late-bound only

var connection2 = new CrmConnection("Crm")
{
    ServiceConfigurationInstanceMode = ServiceConfigurationInstanceMode.PerInstance
};
```